# Store table as recordset of Dynaset type

Tags: ms-access, dao, recordset

I am passing a table in the current database to a recordset with 2 dimensions. Currently:

```
Public Sub MySub(obj As Variant)
   Dim dbs As DAO.Database
   Dim tbl As DAO.Recordset

   Set dbs = CurrentDb
   Set tbl = dbs.OpenRecordset("TABLE")
   tbl.MoveLast
   Records = tbl.GetRows(tbl.RecordCount)

Stop
...
End Sub
```

Stepping through in my locals window (and checking in the immediate window), I can see that the `tbl.RecordCount = 1074` but Records is still only getting the active record with all of the fields, i.e. `Records` Type is `Variant(0 to 37, 0 to 0)`.

I am able to execute a similar approach when storing a query. I have also tried the syntax:

```
Set tbl = dbs.OpenRecordset("TABLE",dbOpenDynaset)
```

And

```
Set tbl = dbs.OpenRecordset("TABLE",dbOpenTable)
```

The former had the same issue, and the latter returned Run-time error '3219'.

---

Edit: example of GetRows with Query (see comments)

```
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rsQuery = dbs.OpenRecordset("QUERY", dbOpenDynaset)
varRecords = rsQuery.GetRows(rsQuery.RecordCount)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had read the [GetRows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-getrows-method-dao?f1url=https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=de-DE&k=k(dao360.chm1053362);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version=v15)&rd=true) Docs, you would have recognized, that`GetRows`returns records from the actual cursor position and moves the cursor to the next not retrieved row (like`.Move`).

As you move the cursor to the last record(`tbl.MoveLast`), no more records are remaining to get.

Solution:

Just move the cursor to the beginning of the Recordset and everything is fine

```vb
tbl.MoveLast
tbl.MoveFirst
Records = tbl.GetRows(tbl.RecordCount)
```

dbOpenTable raises error 3219, if opened table is not local and `.OpenRecordset("TABLE",dbOpenDynaset)`is equal to `.OpenRecordset("TABLE")`as`dbOpenDynaset`is the default value, for non-local tables. (Docs reveal that too ;)

Comment: Thank you. I do my best to read as much documentation as I can before asking a question. For my own edification, do you know why I don't need to MoveLast/MoveFirst before .GetRows when I use it with a query? See edit for syntax...

Comment: And did you read the [.RecordCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-recordcount-property-dao)-doc (press`F1`key on the code you want to have the docs for).. But it will tell you that you have to move Last/First to get correct count, but that has impoct on executiontime.  Without a proper RecordCount you can check the recordset for reached .Eof (the end) and repeat`tbl.GetRows(tbl.RecordCount)`till it has reached it.